# ASP.NET Web.config CustomErrors not working for the webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a simple webservice with two webmethods.

**https://localhost/Sub/WS/Dash.asmx/test_error_methodnameXXXXXXXXXXX**

When i call the above request from the browser. It gives me a error message saying something like this:-

> System.InvalidOperationException: **test_error_methodnameXXXXXXXXXXX Web
>   Service method name is not valid.**    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type,
>   HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
>   Boolean& abortProcessing)

I tried to make a work around with the help of web.config file as follows:-

```
<system.web>    
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Sub/ErrorPage/AppErrors.aspx">
       <error statusCode="500" redirect="500.aspx" />
    </customErrors>       
</system.web>
```

Here in this case, the ***redirection is not happening*** to the 500.aspx page or the AppErrors.aspx.
I can see the change happening, if i change the value in the mode attribute..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the fix with the help of web.config.

Stick

```
<diagnostics suppressReturningExceptions="true"/>
```

Comment: Is there a way to either change what this error says or redirect it to a different page? This currently gives me a blank page that just says "An error occurred on the server." I would like to redirect that to a custom error page if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To call web methods for javascript you should mark your webservice as a script service.

```
[ScriptService]
public class MyService : WebService
{

}
```

Include a reference to it in script manager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="_scriptManager" runat="server">
  <Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="Dash.asmx" />
  </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Call it in js

```
try {
    Dash.MyService.ErrorMethodName();
}
catch(exception){
    //handle exception
}
finally {
    //round up
}
```

Comment: It is already marked as scriptservice. That is fine. The problem i am facing is the handling of the InvalidOperationException message, when someone call the webservice method directly from the browser location bar..

Comment: the javascript try catch will help you there

Comment: But this thing is not called from client side... I want to make this change to give the appropriate message and thus to prevent the content spoofing from the malicious user. test_error_methodnameXXXXXXXXXXX does not exist in the web-service.

Comment: I tried with the help of web.config CustomErrors, but the redirection is not happening..

Comment: Redirection will not happen automatically, in case you detect an error in javascript, you will have to redirect yourself, by setting the `location.href = CUSTOM_ERROR_URL`

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the javascript.. I am trying to call the WS method directly from the browser address bar such as https://localhost/Sub/WS/Dash.asmx/some_methodX  . So that is why i was trying to handle the exception gracefully by redirecting it to the respective error page of our app.

Comment: The purpose of the message is to prevent the XSS attack by the malicious user. So that he cannot add too much long text info in the place of the method name and misled the app user into it..